# Playground simple Date() is printing value taking into cosideration my time zone

Tags: swift, date, nsdate, swift-playground

It seems that for first three lines in the screenshot the TimeZone is not applied(`ok` -  according to documentation it should be like this), but for the last one it seem to be GMT+2 (my current time zone).

Anyone has explanation why for the last line playground is presenting date taking into consideration my system TimeZone?

[image: example]

Comment: I think a playground shows a `Date` value using `description(with: .current)` which is why the last line is different.

Comment: I have the same suspicion, but couldn't find any documentation about this 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Playground has its own custom rules for the gutter display. They are generally more friendly forms of the output. For another example, see `UIColor`, which has a radically different (and very custom) output in Playgrounds.

See the docs for `CustomPlaygroundDisplayConvertible` for the full list of types that get special Playgrounds handling, and how to provide custom handling for your own types.

Keep in mind, of course, that all of these descriptions are purely for informal and debugging use, and none are appropriate for actually displaying to users. See `DateFormatter` for how to format a date for humans. (You likely know this already, but for people reading along it can be a helpful reminder.)

Comment: Interestingly, though, `Date().playgroundDescription` fails. Yet this is exactly the requirement to be met for CustomPlaygroundDisplayConvertible. So something further must be going on.

Comment: Correct. Date gets custom handling from Playgrounds (it's in the list). It's not implemented as CustomPlaygroundDisplayConvertible. I'm not sure whether you can even implement all the special formats with CustomPlaygroundDisplayConvertible. But more importantly, this lets you override Playgrounds' formatting using your own `extension Date: CustomPlaygroundDisplayConvertible`. (You couldn't do that if Date already conformed.)